# Twisted front tyre

Tags: tire

After fixing a front wheel puncture and refitting the inner tube and tyre I noticed that the tyre was slightly twisted on the wheel rim. I put the wheel back on the bike and spun it to make sure the actual wheel was ok and it's definitely the tyre that's twisted and not the wheel. I even took it off again, removed the tyre and inner tube and put it all back again making sure everything was ok and it looked ok until I pumped the tyre up again to see it was still twisted.
Could the fact that I rode the bike after I got the puncture, a few hundred yards to reach a pedestrianised area have caused the tyre to distort somehow ?

Comment: When did you buy the tyre or replace it? Precisely, what was roughtly the millage on that tyre before the problem?

I rode my bike under identical incident, but around 1.5 miles i.e. even more than you. Check for truing and if it still doesn't solve it, then it is your tyre for sure. Also, how long have you been using the tyres? Or, when did you get those tyres?

Comment: It's a new bike, bought it in April. Mileage roughly 200

Comment: 1. If it is not extremely troublesome, take those out again, but check the inner side of the tyre to see if there is something obviously wrong that you can feel. 

2. I am not sure if it is feasible, but could you possibly fit the inner tube inside the tyre (without attaching it to the wheel) and pump the inner tube to see if it is the inner tube that has gone wrong? It may not be possible to know until you inflate it, that's one of the reason why you don't notice anything until it is inflated. Try and let us know.

Comment: I'd recommend that you lower the pressure in the tube to about 15 psi (enough to firm up the tire and tube), then go around and flex the tire to make sure the tire bead is totally seated on the rim all the way around and on both sides. If you are holding the tire and rim in both hands, bend the tire away from you to pull up on the tire bead.

Comment: @WTHarper       +1 for recommending the enforcement of optimum, not high tyre pressure. I ASSUMED that he did it already :P

Comment: I did pump the inner tube up and check the inside of the tyre when I took it out the second time, to check if  everything was ok, and it looked fine.

Comment: Can't do anything more this evening but tomorrow I'll remove the inner tube once more and check everything again

Comment: Ok guys, I've taken the tube out again and tried all your recommendations but to no avail, tyre looks twisted again when pumped up fully. I'm gonna take it to Evans Cycles where I bought it and see what they have to say. I'll let you know....

Comment: A picture would be real helpful.

Comment: How do you post pictures on here ?

Comment: @PhilB You can edit your question and click the image icon.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the tire has become damaged, but if you rode on a flat tire I'd be more likely to suspect that the rim has been bent slightly.

Remove the tire from the rim and carefully check the rim -- sight tangentially to the rim edge and look for any spot where the rim flange moves in or out as the wheel rotates.  If you find such a spot, bike shops generally have tools to remove small bends in the wheel flange.

Also, with the tire off, rotate the tire in your hands while observing the beads.  If a metal bead is bent you may see the bead waver in or out.  A bent bead can possibly be corrected, though there is risk of the bead breaking.  A "bruised" tire, where the cord in the tire has weakened, should be discarded.

When mounting the tire, you generally should inflate once, deflate, then inflate partially again.  With the tire about half inflated, inspect it on both sides to assure that the tire bead is uniformly seated behind the rim.  If a spot is "off" you can generally work it one direction or the other with your hands.

Poor tire seating can occur if the tube has an oversized patch (or multiple patches in one place) such that the tube does not inflate uniformly.  If you have such a tube, discard it, except in emergency situations.  When repairing a tube use the smallest patch that can be reasonably be made to work, and beware of patches near each other or a patch too near the stem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either the bead of the tire or the ridge of the wheel that holds the bead was damaged and lets an area of the tire bulge or bubble out in one area.  It took a bit of looking, but does it look anything like the pics 3/4 of the way down [this thread](http://forums.roadbikereview.com/general-cycling-discussion/keep-getting-bubble-my-tire-191779.html)?

Comment: No, it's nowhere near as bad looking as that, It's not a bulge, it's a twist.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is that there is a weakness in your inner tube. Take the inner tube off the wheel and inflate it gently. If there's an area that bugles (especially if it's in the same location where your wheel bulges), that's probably the issue. If so, replace the inner tube.

Something like this can happen as a result of a flat tire, or the repair of a flat. It could also be due to normal manufacturing variances that can take time to reveal themselves.

Also possible is that the tire tread is damaged. Check for signs of wear or weakness in your tire's side walls, both inside and out. Also make sure that the tire bead (which 'grips' the wheel rim to hold the tire in place) is not damaged or worn. If it is, replace it, especially if it still bulges with a new inner tube.

Comment: Just bought new inner tube and changed it, pumped it up and tyre looks good again.

Comment: ...wait, if this was helpful, who downvoted? At least say why it wasn't helpful for future viewers.

Comment: @PhilB: If this was the solution to your problem, you should "accept" it, by clicking the checkmark next to it. You should also upvote any answers that helped you, or are good quality answers.